# CreateDeploymentUtility option into SSIS 2012 packages

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I use SSIS 2012 and want to set the value True to    CreateDeploymentUtility option. The package contain an Execute SQL Task that insert a value into a sql table. 
I search for this Option in : Solution Explorer -> Properties -> Deployment Utilities but i don't found it. There I have only 'Server Name' and 'Server Project Path' options. 
How can I set True for CreateDeploymentUtility option?
Please help me!!
Thanks!!!

Comment: [Create a Deployment Utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137952.aspx)

Comment: Thanks but in 2012 version i can't find it. Another solution Please?

Answer (score 2):

There are two different deployment models available to you with the 2012 release of SSIS. The new model, called project deployment model, treats all of your SSIS packages as class files that get "compiled" into a .ispac file, much as .net files get turned into an assembly. This .ispac file then gets deployed into the database into a dedicated catalog, SSISDB. Very cool stuff and by default when you create a project in SSIS 2012, this is the model it will use.

The second deployment model, the classic one familiar to SSIS developers from 2005 on is called the package deployment model. Right click on the SSIS project and you will have an option for converting from project deployment to package deployment.

Note that there are incompatible features between the two. Project level Connection Managers are only available in the Project Deployment Model and the last time I tried to convert a project from package to project deployment model, it switched the configuration to package and project parameters.